# Javascript string variable with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't understand why I can't use a variable for the regex string. See link: http://jsfiddle.net/nmWuw/1/

It works without the variable but not when a variable is used for the regex. I escaped my backslashes as well. Output should be '1,234,567,890'.

Comment: Sounds like someone needs to spend 2 minutes reading the documentation.

Comment: Proper demo: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/nmWuw/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var regex = "/\\d(?=(?:\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, '$&,'";
```

That is a string.  It is not a regexp object and a replacement string.  When it is passed to `replace`, it is one parameter, not two.  You need to pass both parameters separately:

```
var regex = /\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
var replace = '$&,';
var num = 1234567890;

alert(String(num).replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$&,'));
alert(String(num).replace(regex, replace));
alert(regex);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmWuw/3/

---

Note that you *could* define them in one call, if you really wanted to, using an array and `apply`:

```
var regex = [/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$&,'];
alert(String.prototype.replace.apply(num, regex));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmWuw/6/

This is hardly a good idea, however -- it's *much* harder to read and much less intuitive.

Comment: Oh geez...I didn't even see that mistake. Brainfart on my part. Thanks.